# What does redirection with >| do?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

When should you use `>|` for redirecting output to a file instead of just `>`?

The explanation given when I was shown this was that it guaranteed the target file was truncated first. But I thought `>` already implied that.

Is `>|` useful?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's an explicit bypass of `noclobber` option.

That way, you can overwrite the file even with `noclobber` set.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NoClobber

From `man bash` :

> If the redirection operator is >, and the noclobber option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail if the
>   file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and
>          is a regular file.  If the redirection operator is >|, or the redirection operator is > and the noclobber option to the set builtin
>   command is not enabled, the redirection is attempted  even
>          if the file named by word exists.

Answer (score 9):

From `man bash`:

```
         -C      If set, bash does not overwrite an  existing  file  with
                  the  >,  >&,  and <> redirection operators.  This may be
                  overridden when creating output files by using the redi‐
                  rection operator >| instead of >.
```